# My game crashes every time i load it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

this happens every time i load it, but i dont know how to fix it.

```
16:00:53    launcher    Preparing to launch minecraft client for 1.8.9  
16:00:53    launcher    Checking installations.  
16:00:53    launcher    Minecraft client 1.8.9 is ready to start.  
16:00:53    launcher    Starting!  
16:00:55    launcher    Using default game log configuration client-1.7.xml (outputs XML)  
16:00:57    ave Setting user: ASUfan  
16:00:57    ave (Session ID is token:4918f14dc0964316b0c451978a27eed3:9b055a259386464cb70d5f589d9e008c)  
16:00:59    ave LWJGL Version: 2.9.4  
16:00:59    ave Couldn't set pixel format
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated    
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at 
org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at ave.ap(SourceFile:521)
    at ave.am(SourceFile:363)
    at ave.a(SourceFile:310)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)
```

Answer (score 2):

Either your graphics card is incompatible with Minecraft (usually too old or not good enough) or it's your graphics card driver.

You can try going to your system settings (assuming you're on Windows), to the "Device manager" and there should be your graphics card. If it says something like "standard VGA", your graphics card is probably not "good" enough to run Minecraft (or there is none at all). If it is something else, you can try to update its driver in the device's properties menu. If that doesn't help, your PC can't run Minecraft.

There are some really complicated modifications to run it with the CPU instead of the GPU, but they should only be done by experts and the game would be incredibly slow anyway.

More information on your problem and what you can do is [here](http://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-297).